# #warning and macro evaluation

Tags: c++, macros

I have the following code :

```
#define LIMIT_DATE \"01-03-2010\"

#ifdef LIMIT_DATE
    #if _MSC_VER
        #pragma message ("Warning : this release will expire on " LIMIT_DATE)
    #elif   __GNUC__
        #warning ("Warning : this release will expire on " LIMIT_DATE)
    #endif
#endif
```

The problem is that LIMIT_DATE is not evaluated when printing the warning.

I searched on Google, but didn't found yet the solution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: On GNU? It does in MSVC. Macro's don't expand their macro arguments, and I don't see a way to get this working the way you want.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can just do `#define LIMIT_DATE "01-03-2010"`. I think it's illegal to escape outside a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From gcc preprocessor documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html#index-g_t_0023warning-97)

> Neither #error nor #warning
>   macro-expands its argument. Internal
>   whitespace sequences are each replaced
>   with a single space. The line must
>   consist of complete tokens. It is
>   wisest to make the argument of these
>   directives be a single string
>   constant; this avoids problems with
>   apostrophes and the like.

So it's not possible at least in gcc.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2(VS.80).aspx) this should work for MSVC althrough I don't have access to Visual Studio currently to test this